# Windows - List all non empty directories in a folder and write to file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I found an answer to find all empty directories. I want to do the opposite to find and list non empty directories in a folder. The folders just go one level deep.

```
@echo off
for /d /r %1 %%A in (.) do (
  dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA
)
```

How to modify the above line to find non empty folders ?

Comment: You should define what you consider to be a non empty directory; one which holds top level files; one which holds files on any level, or one which holds files or directories on any level, _(my definition)_.

Comment: Compo is right, I cannot reproduce your problem with respect to his = my definition; anyway, you should change `%1` to `"%~1"` to avoid trouble with paths containing white-spaces...

Comment: @Compo .. given that in my question I mentioned all folders go just one level not empty obviously means does not have even a single file.

Comment: Given that most questions change radically or include a comment stating, 'and what about if there are other folders...', once answers are provided; and given that some like to make their scripts more robust, I felt it worth asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular situation, instead of using `Dir` you could use `Where.exe`, *(Vista+)*, which has a handy `/Q` option, *(enter `Where /?` at the Command Prompt for usage information)*.

From cmd.exe:

```bat
For /D %A In (*) Do @Where/Q "%A":*>Nul&&Echo %A
```

From a batch file:

```bat
@For /D %%A In (*) Do @Where/Q "%%A":*>Nul&&Echo %%A
```

---

Conversely with a small change you can report those without files:

From cmd.exe:

```bat
For /D %A In (*) Do @Where/Q "%A":*>Nul||Echo %A
```

From a batch file:

```bat
@For /D %%A In (*) Do @Where/Q "%%A":*>Nul||Echo %%A
```

---

In the above examples, if the string between the parentheses contains a path, e.g. `MyFolder\*`, `"C:\Some Location\*` or `..\RelPath\*` you can optionally use `Echo %~nxA` / `Echo %%~nxA` if you prefer the output to be just the directory name.

Answer (score 1):

Simply identify the directories with a non-zero `Count`. Using the `-Directory` switch will require PowerShell 3.0 or higher.

```
@ECHO OFF
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-ChildItem -Directory |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { if ((Get-ChildItem $_).Count -ne 0) { $_.Name } })"
```

Usage:

```
C:>CALL get-nonemptydirs.bat
d2
junk
others
t t t
xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple PowerShell script that will find all directories (within a directory) that have contents within them:

```
((Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "C:\PATH-TO-FOLDER" | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | Where {$_.GetFiles().Count -ne 0} | select FullName).FullName
```

If you want to write the results to a file, just append the following to the end:

```
| out-file -FilePath "C:\PATH-TO-OUTFILE\FILE.txt"
```

Full script:

```
((Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "C:\PATH-TO-FOLDER" | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | Where {$_.GetFiles().Count -ne 0} | select FullName).FullName | Out-File -FilePath "C:\PATH-TO-OUTFILE\FILE.txt"
```